# Get the cell range overlapped by chart area

Tags: excel, vba, charts, range

I am having several charts in one Excel sheet,
In another Excel sheet i am creating a table to list all the charts that are present in above sheet,I can find the chart names and in which sheet they are present, along with chart type.

But I want to know what is the cell range of this chart, i.e. on top of what cells the chart object is located. How do I get this?

Here is my code

```
    Enum myEnum
  xl3DArea = -4098
xl3DAreaStacked = 78
xl3DAreaStacked100 = 79
xl3DBarClustered = 60
xl3DBarStacked = 61
xl3DBarStacked100 = 62
xl3DColumn = -4100
xl3DColumnClustered = 54
xl3DColumnStacked = 55
xl3DColumnStacked100 = 56
xl3DLine = -4101
xl3DPie = -4102
xl3DPieExploded = 70
xlArea = 1
xlAreaStacked = 76
xlAreaStacked100 = 77
xlBarClustered = 57
xlBarOfPie = 71
xlBarStacked = 58
xlBarStacked100 = 59
xlBubble = 15
xlBubble3DEffect = 87
xlColumnClustered = 51
xlColumnStacked = 52
xlColumnStacked100 = 53
xlConeBarClustered = 102
xlConeBarStacked = 103
xlConeBarStacked100 = 104
xlConeCol = 105
xlConeColClustered = 99
xlConeColStacked = 100
xlConeColStacked100 = 101
xlCylinderBarClustered = 95
xlCylinderBarStacked = 96
xlCylinderBarStacked100 = 97
xlCylinderCol = 98
xlCylinderColClustered = 92
xlCylinderColStacked = 93
xlCylinderColStacked100 = 94
xlDoughnut = -4120
xlDoughnutExploded = 80
xlLine = 4
xlLineMarkers = 65
xlLineMarkersStacked = 66
xlLineMarkersStacked100 = 67
xlLineStacked = 63
xlLineStacked100 = 64
xlPie = 5
xlPieExploded = 69
xlPieOfPie = 68
xlPyramidBarClustered = 109
xlPyramidBarStacked = 110
xlPyramidBarStacked100 = 111
xlPyramidCol = 112
xlPyramidColClustered = 106
xlPyramidColStacked = 107
xlPyramidColStacked100 = 108
xlRadar = -4151
xlRadarFilled = 82
xlRadarMarkers = 81
xlStockHLC = 88
xlStockOHLC = 89
xlStockVHLC = 90
xlStockVOHLC = 91
xlSurface = 83
xlSurfaceTopView = 85
xlSurfaceTopViewWireframe = 86
xlSurfaceWireframe = 84
xlXYScatter = -4169
xlXYScatterLines = 74
xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers = 75
xlXYScatterSmooth = 72
xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers = 73

End Enum

Sub ListChartInfo()
'Update 20141112
    Dim appExcel As Application
    Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim path As String
    path = ActiveWorkbook.path
    Dim St As Worksheet
    Dim NewSt As Worksheet
    Dim Cb As ChartObject

    Dim I, K As Long

    'create new excel application object
    Set appExcel = New Application
    'set the applications visible property to false
    appExcel.Visible = False
    'open the workbook with data
    'Set objWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(path & "\Defect Management Dashboard - 20151201 - 002.xlsx")

    'Set objWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Name of Report").Cells(B, 2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set NewSt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ChartInfo")
    I = 1
    NewSt.Cells(I, 1) = "Chart Name"
    NewSt.Cells(I, 2) = "Sheet Name"
    NewSt.Cells(I, 3) = "Chart Type"
    NewSt.Cells(I, 4) = "Shape Range"
    NewSt.Cells(I, 5) = "Full Path"

    'NewSt.Cells(I, 6) = "Type"
    'NewSt.Cells(I, 6) = "Location"
    For sCounter = 2 To 50
        'Either we can put all names in an array , here we are printing all the names in Sheet 2
        path = Sheets("NameofReport").Range("B" & sCounter).Value
        If path = "" Then
            GoTo A
        Else
            Set objWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(path)
            With NewSt

        For Each St In objWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each Cb In St.ChartObjects
                I = I + 1
                .Cells(I, 1).Value = Cb.Name
                .Cells(I, 2).Value = St.Name
                 On Error Resume Next
                '.Cells(I, 3).Value = Cb.Chart.ChartType
                .Cells(I, 3).Value = getEnumName(Cb.Chart.ChartType)

                .Cells(I, 4).Value = Cb.Chart



                .Cells(I, 5).Value = path
                '.Cells(I, 5).Value = Cb.QueryTable.CommandType
                On Error GoTo 0
                '.Cells(I, 7).Value = tb.ResultRange
            Next
        Next
        .Activate
    End With
            'close the workbooks
            objWorkbook.Close
            'close the application
            appExcel.Quit
    End If
A:

Next sCounter
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function getEnumName(eValue As myEnum) As String

  Select Case eValue
    Case -4098
      getEnumName = "xl3DArea"
    Case 78
      getEnumName = "xl3DAreaStacked"
    Case 79
      getEnumName = "xl3DAreaStacked100"
    Case 60
        getEnumName = "xl3DBarClustered"
    Case 61
        getEnumName = "xl3DBarStacked"
    Case 62
        getEnumName = "xl3DBarStacked100"
    Case -4100
        getEnumName = "xl3DColumn"
    Case 54
        getEnumName = "xl3DColumnClustered"
    Case 55
        getEnumName = "xl3DColumnStacked"
    Case 56
        getEnumName = "xl3DColumnStacked100"
    Case -4101
        getEnumName = "xl3DLine"
    Case -4102
        getEnumName = "xl3DPie"
    Case 70
        getEnumName = "xl3DPieExploded"
    Case 1
        getEnumName = "xlArea"
    Case 76
        getEnumName = "xlAreaStacked"
    Case 77
        getEnumName = "xlAreaStacked100"
    Case 57
        getEnumName = "xlBarClustered"
    Case 71
        getEnumName = "xlBarOfPie"
    Case 58
        getEnumName = "xlBarStacked"
    Case 59
        getEnumName = "xlBarStacked100"
    Case 15
        getEnumName = "xlBubble"
    Case 87
        getEnumName = "xlBubble3DEffect"
    Case 51
        getEnumName = "xlColumnClustered"
    Case 52
        getEnumName = "xlColumnStacked"
    Case 53
        getEnumName = "xlColumnStacked100"
    Case 102
        getEnumName = "xlConeBarClustered"
    Case 103
        getEnumName = "xlConeBarStacked"
    Case 104
        getEnumName = "xlConeBarStacked100"
    Case 105
        getEnumName = "xlConeCol"
    Case 99
        getEnumName = "xlConeColClustered"
    Case 100
        getEnumName = "xlConeColStacked"
    Case 101
        getEnumName = "xlConeColStacked100"
    Case 95
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderBarClustered"
    Case 96
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderBarStacked"
    Case 97
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderBarStacked100"
    Case 98
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderCol"
    Case 92
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderColClustered"
    Case 93
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderColStacked"
    Case 94
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderColStacked100"
    Case -4120
        getEnumName = "xlDoughnut"
    Case 80
        getEnumName = "xlDoughnutExploded"
    Case 4
        getEnumName = "xlLine"
    Case 65
        getEnumName = "xlLineMarkers"
    Case 66
        getEnumName = "xlLineMarkersStacked"
    Case 67
        getEnumName = "xlLineMarkersStacked100"
    Case 63
        getEnumName = "xlLineStacked"
    Case 64
        getEnumName = "xlLineStacked100"
    Case 5
        getEnumName = "xlPie"
    Case 69
        getEnumName = "xlPieExploded"
    Case 68
        getEnumName = "xlPieOfPie"
    Case 109
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidBarClustered"
    Case 110
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidBarStacked"
    Case 111
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidBarStacked100"
    Case 112
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidCol"
    Case 106
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidColClustered"
    Case 107
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidColStacked"
    Case 108
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidColStacked100"
    Case -4151
        getEnumName = "xlRadar"
    Case 82
        getEnumName = "xlRadarFilled"
    Case 81
        getEnumName = "xlRadarMarkers"
    Case 88
        getEnumName = "xlStockHLC"
    Case 89
        getEnumName = "xlStockOHLC"
    Case 90
        getEnumName = "xlStockVHLC"
    Case 91
        getEnumName = "xlStockVOHLC"
    Case 83
        getEnumName = "xlSurface"
    Case 85
        getEnumName = "xlSurfaceTopView"
    Case 86
        getEnumName = "xlSurfaceTopViewWireframe"
    Case 84
        getEnumName = "xlSurfaceWireframe"
    Case -4169
        getEnumName = "xlXYScatter"
    Case 74
        getEnumName = "xlXYScatterLines"
    Case 75
        getEnumName = "xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers"
    Case 72
        getEnumName = "xlXYScatterSmooth"
    Case 73
        getEnumName = "xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers"
   Case Else
        getEnumName = "unknown"
  End Select

End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cell range"? Do you mean where the data plotted in the chart is? Or on top of what cells the chart is located?

Comment: I want on top of what cell the chart is located.

Comment: Why `Enum myEnum`? These are already built-into Excel VBA.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally Solved here is my code

```
    Enum myEnum
  xl3DArea = -4098
xl3DAreaStacked = 78
xl3DAreaStacked100 = 79
xl3DBarClustered = 60
xl3DBarStacked = 61
xl3DBarStacked100 = 62
xl3DColumn = -4100
xl3DColumnClustered = 54
xl3DColumnStacked = 55
xl3DColumnStacked100 = 56
xl3DLine = -4101
xl3DPie = -4102
xl3DPieExploded = 70
xlArea = 1
xlAreaStacked = 76
xlAreaStacked100 = 77
xlBarClustered = 57
xlBarOfPie = 71
xlBarStacked = 58
xlBarStacked100 = 59
xlBubble = 15
xlBubble3DEffect = 87
xlColumnClustered = 51
xlColumnStacked = 52
xlColumnStacked100 = 53
xlConeBarClustered = 102
xlConeBarStacked = 103
xlConeBarStacked100 = 104
xlConeCol = 105
xlConeColClustered = 99
xlConeColStacked = 100
xlConeColStacked100 = 101
xlCylinderBarClustered = 95
xlCylinderBarStacked = 96
xlCylinderBarStacked100 = 97
xlCylinderCol = 98
xlCylinderColClustered = 92
xlCylinderColStacked = 93
xlCylinderColStacked100 = 94
xlDoughnut = -4120
xlDoughnutExploded = 80
xlLine = 4
xlLineMarkers = 65
xlLineMarkersStacked = 66
xlLineMarkersStacked100 = 67
xlLineStacked = 63
xlLineStacked100 = 64
xlPie = 5
xlPieExploded = 69
xlPieOfPie = 68
xlPyramidBarClustered = 109
xlPyramidBarStacked = 110
xlPyramidBarStacked100 = 111
xlPyramidCol = 112
xlPyramidColClustered = 106
xlPyramidColStacked = 107
xlPyramidColStacked100 = 108
xlRadar = -4151
xlRadarFilled = 82
xlRadarMarkers = 81
xlStockHLC = 88
xlStockOHLC = 89
xlStockVHLC = 90
xlStockVOHLC = 91
xlSurface = 83
xlSurfaceTopView = 85
xlSurfaceTopViewWireframe = 86
xlSurfaceWireframe = 84
xlXYScatter = -4169
xlXYScatterLines = 74
xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers = 75
xlXYScatterSmooth = 72
xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers = 73

End Enum

Sub ListChartInfo()
'Update 20141112
    Dim appExcel As Application
    Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim path As String
    path = ActiveWorkbook.path
    Dim St As Worksheet
    Dim NewSt As Worksheet
    Dim Cb As ChartObject
    Dim oSeries As Series
    Dim I, K As Long
    Dim co As ChartObject
    'create new excel application object
    Set appExcel = New Application
    'set the applications visible property to false
    appExcel.Visible = False
    'open the workbook with data
    'Set objWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(path & "\Defect Management Dashboard - 20151201 - 002.xlsx")

    'Set objWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Name of Report").Cells(B, 2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set NewSt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Charts")
    I = 1
    NewSt.Cells(I, 1) = "Chart Name"
    NewSt.Cells(I, 2) = "Sheet Name"
    NewSt.Cells(I, 3) = "Chart Type"
    NewSt.Cells(I, 4) = "Chart Location"
    NewSt.Cells(I, 5) = "Full Path"

    'NewSt.Cells(I, 6) = "Type"
    'NewSt.Cells(I, 6) = "Location"
    For sCounter = 2 To 50
        'Either we can put all names in an array , here we are printing all the names in Sheet 2
        path = Sheets("NameofReport").Range("B" & sCounter).Value
        If path = "" Then
            GoTo A
        Else
            Set objWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(path)
            With NewSt

        For Each St In objWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each Cb In St.ChartObjects
                I = I + 1
                .Cells(I, 1).Value = Cb.Name
                .Cells(I, 2).Value = St.Name
                 On Error Resume Next
                '.Cells(I, 3).Value = Cb.Chart.ChartType
                .Cells(I, 3).Value = getEnumName(Cb.Chart.ChartType)
                .Cells(I, 4).Value = "Location:"
                For Each oSeries In Cb.Chart.SeriesCollection
                    .Cells(I, 4).Value = .Cells(I, 4).Value & oSeries.Formula
                Next
                '.Cells(I, 4).Value = Cb.Chart.SeriesCollection.Formula


                .Cells(I, 5).Value = path
                '.Cells(I, 5).Value = Cb.QueryTable.CommandType
                On Error GoTo 0
                '.Cells(I, 7).Value = tb.ResultRange
            Next
        Next
        .Activate
    End With
            'close the workbooks
            'objWorkbook.Close
            'close the application
            'appExcel.Quit
    End If
A:

Next sCounter
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function getEnumName(eValue As myEnum) As String

  Select Case eValue
    Case -4098
      getEnumName = "xl3DArea"
    Case 78
      getEnumName = "xl3DAreaStacked"
    Case 79
      getEnumName = "xl3DAreaStacked100"
    Case 60
        getEnumName = "xl3DBarClustered"
    Case 61
        getEnumName = "xl3DBarStacked"
    Case 62
        getEnumName = "xl3DBarStacked100"
    Case -4100
        getEnumName = "xl3DColumn"
    Case 54
        getEnumName = "xl3DColumnClustered"
    Case 55
        getEnumName = "xl3DColumnStacked"
    Case 56
        getEnumName = "xl3DColumnStacked100"
    Case -4101
        getEnumName = "xl3DLine"
    Case -4102
        getEnumName = "xl3DPie"
    Case 70
        getEnumName = "xl3DPieExploded"
    Case 1
        getEnumName = "xlArea"
    Case 76
        getEnumName = "xlAreaStacked"
    Case 77
        getEnumName = "xlAreaStacked100"
    Case 57
        getEnumName = "xlBarClustered"
    Case 71
        getEnumName = "xlBarOfPie"
    Case 58
        getEnumName = "xlBarStacked"
    Case 59
        getEnumName = "xlBarStacked100"
    Case 15
        getEnumName = "xlBubble"
    Case 87
        getEnumName = "xlBubble3DEffect"
    Case 51
        getEnumName = "xlColumnClustered"
    Case 52
        getEnumName = "xlColumnStacked"
    Case 53
        getEnumName = "xlColumnStacked100"
    Case 102
        getEnumName = "xlConeBarClustered"
    Case 103
        getEnumName = "xlConeBarStacked"
    Case 104
        getEnumName = "xlConeBarStacked100"
    Case 105
        getEnumName = "xlConeCol"
    Case 99
        getEnumName = "xlConeColClustered"
    Case 100
        getEnumName = "xlConeColStacked"
    Case 101
        getEnumName = "xlConeColStacked100"
    Case 95
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderBarClustered"
    Case 96
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderBarStacked"
    Case 97
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderBarStacked100"
    Case 98
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderCol"
    Case 92
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderColClustered"
    Case 93
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderColStacked"
    Case 94
        getEnumName = "xlCylinderColStacked100"
    Case -4120
        getEnumName = "xlDoughnut"
    Case 80
        getEnumName = "xlDoughnutExploded"
    Case 4
        getEnumName = "xlLine"
    Case 65
        getEnumName = "xlLineMarkers"
    Case 66
        getEnumName = "xlLineMarkersStacked"
    Case 67
        getEnumName = "xlLineMarkersStacked100"
    Case 63
        getEnumName = "xlLineStacked"
    Case 64
        getEnumName = "xlLineStacked100"
    Case 5
        getEnumName = "xlPie"
    Case 69
        getEnumName = "xlPieExploded"
    Case 68
        getEnumName = "xlPieOfPie"
    Case 109
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidBarClustered"
    Case 110
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidBarStacked"
    Case 111
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidBarStacked100"
    Case 112
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidCol"
    Case 106
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidColClustered"
    Case 107
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidColStacked"
    Case 108
        getEnumName = "xlPyramidColStacked100"
    Case -4151
        getEnumName = "xlRadar"
    Case 82
        getEnumName = "xlRadarFilled"
    Case 81
        getEnumName = "xlRadarMarkers"
    Case 88
        getEnumName = "xlStockHLC"
    Case 89
        getEnumName = "xlStockOHLC"
    Case 90
        getEnumName = "xlStockVHLC"
    Case 91
        getEnumName = "xlStockVOHLC"
    Case 83
        getEnumName = "xlSurface"
    Case 85
        getEnumName = "xlSurfaceTopView"
    Case 86
        getEnumName = "xlSurfaceTopViewWireframe"
    Case 84
        getEnumName = "xlSurfaceWireframe"
    Case -4169
        getEnumName = "xlXYScatter"
    Case 74
        getEnumName = "xlXYScatterLines"
    Case 75
        getEnumName = "xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers"
    Case 72
        getEnumName = "xlXYScatterSmooth"
    Case 73
        getEnumName = "xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers"
   Case Else
        getEnumName = "unknown"
  End Select

End Function
```

I have used .Cells(I, 4).Value = .Cells(I, 4).Value & oSeries.Formula
to get the series of cells

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TopLeftCell` and `BottomRightCell` properties of the `ChartObject` object. In the example below, I have highlighted in light orange the cells overlapped by the chart area; and this is indeed the range returned in the MsgBox.

```
Dim co As ChartObject
Dim r As Range

Set co = ActiveChart.Parent
Set r = Range(co.TopLeftCell, co.BottomRightCell)
MsgBox r.Address
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but your example is using ActiveChart.Parent , but in my case I am using a loop For Each Cb In St.ChartObjects In this loop even if I access Range(Cb.TopLeftCell, Cb.BottomRightCell), I get nothing can you please tell me how can i use this in loop ?

Comment: I could, but I'd like you to have a go at it first.

Comment: Finally Solved                                                                                           For Each oSeries In Cb.Chart.SeriesCollection
                    .Cells(I, 4).Value = .Cells(I, 4).Value & oSeries.Formula
                Next

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this to get the range for legend / data series of the charts:

```
Dim oSeries As Series
Dim oChart As ChartObject
Dim oWS As Worksheet

For Each oWS In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each oChart In oWS.ChartObjects
        For Each oSeries In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
            Debug.Print oSeries.Formula
        Next
    Next
Next
```

you have to extract that data of course from the formula.

BTW: If you use late binding you have to define oSeries as Object of course. If you use early binding (as your code indicates as you use something like Dim objWorkbook As Workbook) there shouldn't be a need for that Enum stuff as all of that constants are already declared in the lib.

Comment: SeriesCollection is not the property that is supported by chartObject,any other suggestion ?

Comment: here on my end the solution works ... have checked it with ActiveChart instead of Cb ... but this shouldn't be a problem. Which Excel version do you use?

Comment: ah ... I see the problem. Cb is declared as ChartObject ... then we have to call the Chart property of that object first. Have adjusted my example above